# gulp - Error events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: gulp

I am getting folowing issue when i am trying to run the gulp.
I am using laravel 5.2 and gulp 3.9.1

```
[16:40:58] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/embassy/embassyv1/gulpfile.js
[16:40:58] Starting 'build'...
[16:40:58] Finished 'build' after 14 ms
[16:40:58] Starting 'serve'...
[16:40:58] Finished 'serve' after 10 ms
[16:40:58] Starting 'default'...
[16:40:58] Finished 'default' after 15 μs

events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
            ^
Error: EPERM, chmod '/var/www/html/embassy/embassyv1'
embassy@EMB-NEW-VM-UBUNTU:/var/www/html/embassy/embassyv1$ [Tue Feb 21 16:40:58 2017] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
```

Comment: Please add code to your question, otherwise we can't do anything.

Comment: Do you mean the gulp file for the issue. Or which code do you want for gulp

Comment: Depends on where the error comes from. Start with the gulp file, so when can see what it does.

Comment: This is my gulpfile.js  http://embassycommunity.in/embassy/embassyv1/public/metronic/assets/gulpfile.js